# How secure is Django Admin interface

Tags: python, django, web-applications, django-admin

I have couple of apps on internet and want *to serve static files* for those apps using another Django App. *I simply can't afford to use Amazon Web Services for my pet-projects.*

So, I want to setup an Admin interface where I can manage static files easily. The following are the actions I am thinking to include in admin.

1. Upload, delete static files
2. Grouping static files (creating new folders, adding new/ existing files to it); I am not sure If it is possible.
3. checking my models

Thus, I would like to know how secure is Django-Admin interface!

How secure it is when compared to our famous sites like Yahoo, Facebook, Google Login's.. (at least in terms of "cracking".. is django admin can be cracked easily?)

Answer (score 0):

Besides serving static files through django is considered a bad idea, the django admin itself is pretty safe. You can take additional measure by securing it via .htaccess and force https access on it. You could also restrict access to a certain IP. If the admin is exposed to the whole internet you should at least be careful when choosing credentials. Since I don't know how secure Google and Yahoo really are, I can't compare to them.

Comment: then.. what's the best way to serve static files? I am thinking to host it on a PaaS.. any better option?

Comment: actually what I am asking now is out of the scope of this question but.. I am looking for a free static file server which is quite "smart" .. I even want to generate JSON objects so I can search files easily

Answer (score -3):

How secure is a Google Login ;) ? You can't tell as you can't look behind the scenes (**Update**: Of Google Login of course.). I would guess that Django's admin code is pretty safe, as it's used in lots of production systems. Still, beside the code, it also matters how you set it up. In the end, it depends on the level of security you need.

Comment: Actually, you can [browse the Django source code](https://github.com/django/django).

Comment: @Gumbo: Sure. I meant the "Google Login".